# Specific single propery in LINQ aggregation using GroupBy

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

this is my entity class:

```
public class DettaglioRiga
{
    public int OrdId { get; set; }
    public string OrdStato { get; set; }
    public string ProdCodice { get; set; }
    public string ProdModelNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProdNome { get; set; }
    public string ProdTipo { get; set; }
    public int ProdQuantitaAcquistata { get; set; }
    public int ProdQuantitaTotale { get; set; }
    public double ProdCostoSingolo { get; set; }
    public double ProdCostoTotale { get; set; }
    public double ProdSpeseSpedizione { get; set; }

    public DettaglioRiga()
    {
    }
}
```

Then I fill a collection named **ordiniFiltrati** and now I need to create an aggregated collection as follow:

```
List<DettaglioRiga> listaProdotti = ordiniFiltrati
    .Where(p => p.ProdTipo == "PRODOTTO")
    .OrderBy(q => q.ProdNome)
    .ToList();

var listaProdottiFiltrata = listaProdotti
    .Distinct()
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.ProdNome })
    .Select(group => new DettaglioRiga
    {                    
        ProdNome = group.Key.ProdNome,
        ProdCodice = group.ProdCodice,   // (?)I cannot get this
        ProdQuantitaTotale = group.Sum(D => D.ProdQuantitaTotale), 
        ProdCostoSingolo = group.Sum(C => C.ProdCostoSingolo) 
    });
```

Basically I need to get the value of "ProdCodice" and assign to the new **DettaglioRiga** object. I cannot get it, any hints?

EDIT: I will add more details:

Thank you for the answer but my case is a little tricky. Here's my data:

```
ProdCodice  ProdNome
S-3850759   Driller A
S-3850755   Driller A
S-3850759   Driller A
S-3851196   Driller B
```

Basically I need to group the ProdCodice compared to ProdName. In this example I would have a row with:

```
ProdCodice  ProdNome
S-3850759   Driller A
S-3850755   Driller A
S-3851196   Driller B
```

I think I have to group both ProdName and ProdCodice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to add `ProdCodice` to your grouping key:

```
var listaProdottiFiltrata = listaProdotti
    .Distinct()
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.ProdNome, g.ProdCodice })  // <-- added another value to group on
    .Select(group => new DettaglioRiga
    {                    
        ProdNome = group.Key.ProdNome,
        ProdCodice = group.Key.ProdCodice,   
        ProdQuantitaTotale = group.Sum(D => D.ProdQuantitaTotale), 
        ProdCostoSingolo = group.Sum(C => C.ProdCostoSingolo) 
    });
```

or use an aggregate function to specify *which* one you want.  Some options:

```
ProdCodice = group.First().ProdCodice,   

ProdCodice = group.Max(g => g.ProdCodice),
```

Comment: Thank you Stanley, I added more detail to my request. As far as I can see, I would create ProdCodice by aggregating both 'Nome' and 'Codice', right?

Comment: Seems correct but unfortunately it does not aggreage the values as expected. Basically I have to take the first occurence using a GroupBy 'ProdCodice' and 'ProdName'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<DettaglioRiga> listaProdotti = ordiniFiltrati.Where(p => p.ProdTipo == "PRODOTTO").OrderBy(q => q.ProdNome).ToList();
            var listaProdottiFiltrata = listaProdotti.Distinct().GroupBy(g => new { g.ProdNome }).Select(group => new  
{                    
    ProdNome = group.Key.ProdNome,
    ProdCodice = group.First().ProdCodice,   // (?)I cannot get this
    ProdQuantitaTotale = group.Sum(D => D.ProdQuantitaTotale), 
    ProdCostoSingolo = group.Sum(C => C.ProdCostoSingolo) 
});
```